# extract value from a json object in a database column using linq

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Suppose I've two columns in my database table `Employees` as below :

```
EmpId                     ImageData
-----   --------------------------------------------
  1     {"path":"~/Content/Image.png","type":".pdf"}
```

Now, How to place a condition in my linq `where()` clause to check if the `path` of `ImageData` is equals to `~/Content/Image.png`?

I want to do something like this :

```
var data = db.Employees
           .Where(x => JObject.Parse(x.ImageData)["path"] == "~/Content/Image.png")
          .ToList();
```

Is it possible? Or, What is the right way to achieve this? Thanks :)

**Update**

As per Steve Ford's suggestion, I'm having the below exception :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `JToken` you receive from `JObject.Parse` to a string:

```
var data = db.Employees
           .Where(x => (string)JObject.Parse(x.ImageData)["path"] == "~/Content/Image.png")
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm having an exception. Please, have a look at my updated part of my question.